# Manually modifying data in Ruby on Rails without user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie here. I have a little question about Rails. I'd like to know if there's a way to modify values in the database by writing a piece of code somewhere in the app to change something without any user input or doing console commands. For example, let's say you have a users controller and wish to set a particular user's attributes to user ID number 1 every time you start your app.

For example, something like this gets set up on server start:

> user ID: 1 username: 'User' pass:'Userpass' etc...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `seed`.

Open `db/seed.rb` and just write required code to create the object. In your case:

```
User.create!(username: "myusername", password: "mypassword"...)
```

Then just hit following command from terminal which will persist a new user to your db and you can use that user anytime even after re-starting your application:

```
rake db:seed # Need to run only once while application setup.
```

More info is available under [Migrations and Seed Data in Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, this should work fine I'll test it soon and post the results. Just a quick question about this seed method, what ID will be given to the user when he is created ? Will it be the next available one just like when creating a new user over your methods in the controllers or can that be assigned additionally using the seed ?

Comment: `>> Will it be the next available one <<` - Correct... You cannot assign `id` explicitly. It's auto-increment column, however, if you will run `rake db:seed` just after app setup, `id=1` will be the available id and will get assigned to this user.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks a lot !